# Voice activity detection (VAD) libraries 2023

Tags: voice, software-implementation

I am trying to use (not implement VAD algorithm) voice activity detection to get timestamps for a given audio but facing hard time doing so.

---

What I am trying to achieve ?

Find an offline library for voice activity detection

---

What I have ?
I have an audio file (mp3)

---

What I am trying to get ?
Given an audio file (mp3), script/library should return the indexes/timestamps of human voice.

---

What I tried ?

Used https://github.com/kdavis-mozilla/vad.js and tested VAD with audio stream but it is returning whether it detects voice or not, but no way to get timestamps of when the script detects human voice.

---

Example ?

Script should take an audio file with 1 minute duration where human voice starts from 00:00:05 to 00:00:20 and 00:00:39 to 00:00:45 and 00:00:50 to 00:00:60 and return timestamps as output like

```
[[00:00:05,00:00:20],[00:00:39,00:00:45],[00:00:50,00:00:60]]
```

---

Can you suggest me a library or Git repository for my scenario ?

[I have seen similar question which was asked 10 years ago](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2386/libraries-for-voice-activity-detection-not-speech-recognition) but I'm not sure if the answers are still relevant

Answer (score 1):

I did a project once where I was trying to use machine learning to detect the tone of single syllable words in mandarin (there are 4 or 5 unique tones which change the meaning of the word). In order to do this I had a dataset of recorded audio files which I needed to find sections in which people were talking and sections that were quiet. To do this I used the Librosa library in python. If you are able to use python the [librosa.effects.split](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.effects.split.html) function appears to be exactly what you are looking for. The description is "Split an audio signal into non-silent intervals."

Comment: VAD algorithms are usually designed to work in many different environments: voice in ambient noise , voice in music, etc. Voice in silence is rarely useful, and doesn’t require any complicated algorithm (simple power levels are sufficient).

Comment: Maybe try following this guide. It looks like Librosa has the functionality you are looking [for](https://librosa.org/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_vocal_separation.html)

I also found this [repository](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad)

Comment: Thank you for the answer