# What language or framework would you use to develop and test natively algorithms meant to be ported on an embedded hardware later?

Tags: algorithms, audio-processing

I am trying to find a nice clean solution to this problem since some days now, and couldn't make myself to stick to a solution.

I need to develop some stream and block processing for audio, including cascaded biquad, FT and iFT, FIR, dynamic correction. The whole audio chain will be embedded either in a DSP or on a ARM running Xenomai Linux.

What I am looking for is a way to quickly compile and test bits of codes, getting audio in and out, and in a language that will allow me to target a broad range of devices. (Would be C or Cpp surely).

I don't want to choose the definitive platform now because I don't know yet how much processing power will be required to make my full project runs.

Here are some tought:

- I am using Gnu Octave but afaik it will not compile a real-time pipeline and the code is hardly portable.
- I tried Audio Weaver from DSP Concepts (which is great) but the targets DSP are limited and the engine is proprietary.
- I looked at Faust which is a very promising framework for audio (even able to generate Cpp code), but unfortunately it was designed with stream processing in mind and not meant to process blocks of data
- I looked at some LabView + FPGA solution but the price and licensing is just WOW !
- I looked at some IDE from Ti and AD but there also the price is too high.
- Using a simple VST or ALSA framework might be ok but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: i am opposed to closing this question.  i see there is a single vote to close.

Comment: you can stream audio by processing blocks of data.  the mechanism to do that is **double buffering**.  processing by blocks of samples makes code efficient.  //"*The whole audio chain will be embedded either in a DSP or on a ARM running Xenomai Linux.*"// --- do you know which one?  if DSP, which DSP?  that choice makes a difference.

Comment: I don't know at the moment. I hope everything will fit in a ARM SOM but there are other stuf going on (webserver, networking, display...). The costs are low for Linux SOM these times. If I have to defer to a DSP, I will surely be on a Ti C6000 architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your opposition on the closing. 
The question looks development/hardware related but really touches the heart the heart of the signal processing subject. I am also going to ask it on the Electronics Stack Exchange.

Comment: maybe post to the Software Engineering SE.

Comment: I found a related Ask: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/912/analogous-library-to-opencv-for-audio-processing-analysis/914#914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled on python, and here is why:

I had no reason to limit myself to a specific language or framework. The target plateform was not specified, but I needed to have proof of concepts for the project, and quick.

I choose python because of its versatility, the profusion of libraries, the speed over other scientific calculation packages, and the scientific community.

And so far so good.

Comment: I would strongly recommend checking out Julia before committing to Python. Julia is *fast*, it has a very active community, it is easy to learn and has all the scientific calculation packages you could ever need.

Comment: Oh yes ! I checked it some years ago when it didn't had that much traction. It is *ridiculously* fast ! Amazing language. 
I didn't remembered it at the time I started to work with python... Will give it a go again.
Thanks for the reminder !